# Fast Exponentiation question: I am not even sure how to read this question, let alone attempt to solve it.

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

The Question is

$$ N=12={ 2 }^{ 2 }+{ 2 }^{ 3 }\\ { M }^{ 2 }\equiv 51(mod\quad 59)\\ What\quad is\quad { M }^{ 12 }(mod\quad 59)? $$

The solution is in the book says its 7. I am not sure what I am supposed to do with N, in relation to the question. Thank you for any insight.

Comment: $M^{2}\equiv-2^3$ so $M^{12}\equiv 2^{18}\equiv(2^6)^3\equiv5^3\bmod59$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of $N$ is to show that if $M^2 \equiv 51 \pmod {59}$, then $$M^{12} = M^{2^2 + 2^3} = M^{2^2} M^{2^3} = (M^2)^2 ((M^2)^2)^2 \equiv (51)^2 ((51)^2)^2 \pmod {59}.$$
Of course, it is easier to write $$M^2 \equiv -8 \pmod {59}$$ so that the squaring operation on $M^2$ is a little less computational.

Comment: Thanks. I was overlooking that.